# imshow doesnt update on qt gui

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, opencv3.0

So I have a program where I'm doing some processing with the OpenCV library and then show the results in a Qt made gui (on a widget). The thing is if i wanted to 'debug' the opencv implementation inside the gui, ie do a imshow of some frames/mask, it creates the window but doesn't refresh it except sporadically.
Trying to add a waitKey(1) to force a refresh just freezes the gui so its another dead end.

Any idea on how to fix this? If its needed I'll try to do a MWE but with the state of my program is a bit difficult to extract the functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a Qt GUI to be responsive, the main thread's event loop must be having control. When it doesn't, the GUI is not responsive. That's all, usually. Any blocking methods like `waitKey`, or anything from Qt itself that begins with `waitFor`, must never be used in the main thread!

Comment: So there is no way to update the imshows? :/

Comment: Of course there is: don't use `waitKey` etc. if you wish to react to a keypress in the gui, use a button, or a global accelerator, or a global event filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well seems that doing a

```
QApplication::ProcessEvents()
```

forces the image to update, albeit really slow, but for debugging purposes it will suffice.